# php how to escape a string for preg_match?

Tags: php

I'am trying to pass a string

```
  preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($my_str).'/i', '', $string);
```

but I get an error

```
preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '\'
```

is there any other solutions to escape those backslashes?

Comment: You have to pass regexp delimiter (/) as 2nd parameter for `preg_quote`

Comment: What is the regular expression you're passing into `preg_quote`? You may need to add a delimiter.

Comment: Can you show us the value of $my_str

Answer (score 1):

Pass the delimiter to the second argument of the [**`preg_quote`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

```
echo preg_replace('/'.preg_quote("$my_str",'~').'/i', '',$string );
                                            ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $my_str contains `/` character in it which you are using as regex delimiter. So you have two solutions,

One, replace the delimiter `/` into anything else which doesn't contain in the variable. For example `~`

```
preg_replace('~'.preg_quote($my_str).'~i', '', $string);
              ^                       ^
```

Second solution, replace all the `/` with `\/` from `$my_str` after `preg_quote`

```
$my_str = str_replace('/', '\/', preg_quote($my_str));
$some_str = preg_replace('/'.$my_str.'/i', '', $string);
```